# Excluding reference list from line numbering

Tags: bibtex, line-numbering

When the `lineno` package is included, all lines are numbered. But I don't want the bibliography to have linenumbers because it is ugly. So is this possible?

[ps. I have used BibTex to create the bibliography]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\section*{Section}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-2]
\cite{goossens93}

\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

creates:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `\nolinenumbers` to disable continuation of numbering.

Comment: wow, that exists. I couldn't find it in the lineno.sty documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Convert my comment into an answer.

Use `\nolinenumbers` to disable continuation of numbering.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\section*{Section}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-2]
\cite{blaine}
\nolinenumbers   % <---
\bibliography{bibtest}
\end{document}
```